# HttpURLConnection not returning anything on first attempt. Subsequent calls return values just fine

Tags: java, android, get

I am developing an Android app which makes GET requests to a website. For some reason, every time I send this request (GET request is sent when a button is clicked), the first attempt doesn't return anything, but the second attempt works. The first attempt does not cause any errors either.

Here is the code:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
        URL url = null;
        try {
            url = new URL(urlString);
            Log.d("testJson", "URL" + urlString);
        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
        try {
            urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000*5);
            urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000*5);
            InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
            json = readStream(in);
            Log.d("testJson", "json" + json);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            urlConnection.disconnect();
        }
    }
});
thread.start();

JSONObject jObj;
JSONObject tracks;
JSONArray items;

if (json != null) {
    try {

        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
        tracks = (JSONObject) jObj.get("tracks");
        items = (JSONArray) tracks.get("items");
        id = items.getJSONObject(0).getString("id");
        Log.d("testJson", id);

        // ... more code
    catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Why does happen and how can I solve this problem?

**UPDATE** I added in the log messages. The first time the app makes a GET request only the first 2 are displayed to the console. The information they report is correct and the same as the second time the button is pressed. The second time I make the GET request, all 3 of the log messages are sent to the console. For some reason the if (json != null) evaluates to false and it doesn't let the other log statement execute. But this shouldn't happen because I already printed what json contained previously. Any thoughts?

**UPDATE 2** For a bit of background, this app makes a GET request to the spotify music library, and returns a song that I search. What is happening with my app is that on the first call, the id is not being returned, but on the second call, it returns the id of the song requested on the first attempt. On the 3rd call, it returns the id of the song requested on the second attempt and so on. I have tried adding the `urlConnection.setConnectTimeout(1000*5);` and `urlConnection.setReadTimeout(1000*5);` lines but it still has the same problem

Comment: did you checked logging the urlString and json for each request? And are you sure that the returned value is from the subsequent calls?

Comment: try with con.setConnectTimeout(connectTimeout);
con.setReadTimeout(socketTimeout);

Comment: Can you post an answer and show where I would put that @Pravin?

Comment: Why you don't use AsyncTask rather than Thread ? its more convenient way i think.

Comment: @jayeshsolanki93 I updated the question. let me know if you need clarification

Comment: @ParasValera I'll try out asynctask. Just did some research and it looks better

Answer (score 0):

I don't have enough reputation to comment right now. So posting here,

try following:

```
urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
urlConnection.connect();
if(urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK ||
    urlConnection.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_CREATED) {
    Log.d("Testing","urlConnection is success");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getInputStream());
    json = readStream(in);
} else {
    Log.d("Testing","urlConnection failed");
    InputStream in = new BufferedInputStream(urlConnection.getErrorStream());
    errorMsg = readStream(in);
    // try printing this error message
}
```

And share your findings.

Comment: I updated my question to include the log statements. Those lines of code actually execute on the first call, it's the last log statement that doesn't

Comment: The connection is successful from the get-go, check out the UPDATE 2 in my question, it explains it better

Comment: @Michel, could you please check one more thing, Is your first response code is a HTTP_CREATED type and next is HTTP_OK type ?